# Stop Using iPhone For Development

Tags: iphone, xcode

So I plugged in an iPhone, and pressed the big <kbd>Use Device For Development</kbd> button, and now I want to disable that, as I no longer need it.

The `Developer` item in `Settings.app` on the device is annoying. How do I **stop using it for development**?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Hold down the Home and Sleep/Wake buttons until you see the Apple logo. Once restarted you will no longer see the Developer entry in Settings.app. You will also need to ignore the device in Xcode or it will just activate the tools again the next time you connect your iPhone.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to right click it in Organizer and hit "Ignore Device" or something along those lines.

Comment: But how do I actually remove the settings entry?

Answer (score 1):

For iPhones without a home button, press the sleep/wake button and the volume down button at the same time until you see "Slide to Power Off".  Proceed to power off the device, and then restart it (hold the sleep/wake button until the Apple logo appears).  Once the device boots, the Developer option in settings should be gone.  Reconnecting the device to Xcode will cause this option to reappear.

Comment: Nice, it worked with iPhone 13 pro max