# iPhone Project Not Running (more than once)

Tags: iphone, xcode, uninstallation, runtime-error, reboot

I have an iPhone app that I'm trying to run on my phone via Xcode.

- It installs and runs without an issue
- I make a change in the source code (negligible, like an NSLog())
- It installs without an issue
- Running causes the error:

  `Error Starting Executable 'myApp'`

  `Don't know how to run. Try "help target".`
- I uninstall the app, and reboot the phone
- It installs and runs without an issue (until I make another change; then I have to repeat this dance)

Needless to say, having to uninstall the app, reboot the phone, and reinitialize the environment (i.e. set prefs) takes an unreasonable amount of time, and is probably indicative of a serious problem. The issue is, the only vague error message I receive gets me nowhere on Google. Where on earth could this issue be coming from?

Comment: troubleshooting steps: do you see this at all on simulator? If you have a running app, can you stop and restart it without changing any code? do you see this on a different device (if available)? can you uninstall then re-install or just restart the device? It is unlikely that it requires both.

Comment: The simulator was running fine. The running app could *not* be restarted on the phone with the uninstall/reboot. I don't have another device available, sorry. And both were required.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With some help from #iphonedev, I figured it out. Turns out it's a glitch in iOS 5 beta. The way to fix it is to [remove the device from Development Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390087/stop-using-iphone-for-development), then re-add it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah just restarting the iPhone with the lock and home buttons fixes this. Had it happen a few times to me